# how to set nonstring value in jsp from bean

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

```
public class Infobean {

private int id;
private String name;
private String sname;
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="id")
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
 // getters and setters
}
```

here i want to set  my Bean id value in jsp page . i am using struts . jsp page gives error that int cannot be cast to string. Help me to fix that problem.

```
 <s:textfield  name="id" id="id" ><s:property value="${id}"/></s:textfield>
```

Comment: It should be `<s:property value="id"/>`. What is the need to have `<s:property>`, in this case? Shouldn't it simply be like `<s:textfield  name="id" id="id" />`?

Comment: what should  i do can u explain me with code

Comment: Everything in JSP is treated as string but the value is treated like object.

Comment: Show you error stack trace.